# Jenkins slave enabling using Powershell remotely

Tags: python, windows, powershell, jenkins

Need help on powershell script for enabling jenkins slave from master. 
Created a powershell script for running a javaws command on remote using psremoting. However, when I run the script the slave is enabled. When I exit the powershell script the slave goes offline.

I wanted to automate enabling jenkins slave nodes using powershell script or any other windows compatible.

Enable-PSRemoting -Force | Out-Null
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value "*" -Force

Set-Item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts * -Force | Out-Null

$server_ip = '**********'

$username = 'localhost\Administrator'

$Pwd = '************************'

$dest_pass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Pwd -AsPlainText -Force

$credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username,$dest_pass

$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server_ip -Credential $credentials

$hs = Invoke-Command -Session $s -ErrorAction Ignore 
{

cmd /k "javaws http://:8080/jenkins/computer//slave-agent.jnlp"
   # cmd /k c:\slave.bat

}

Remove-PSSession -Session $s

Want to correct the above code to enable the slave jenkins node, and exit automatically. 
Please help on fixing this script. 
Thanks.

Comment: Request some help on this. Please add your thoughts.

Comment: so I do it a bit differently. I have scheduled tasks on each of the slaves that starts jenkins agent ( easy way to have agent run as (your_account)) if any agent is stopped - I just trigger a script that attempts to start jenkins slave scheduled task on each slave. 
You can also configure jenkins slave process to run as a service and keep it up this way constantly. Both cases leverage system to store credentials so that You do not have to worry about that any more